# android Reflection on NdefMessage Construction fails

Tags: java, android, arrays, reflection

I want to instantiate an NdefMessage using an NdefRecord with Reflection. Below a simple codeSnippet that really *SHOULD* work, but doesn't:

```
// getting Ndef Message Class OK
Class<?> ndefMessageClass = Class.forName("android.nfc.NdefMessage"); 

//getting NdefRecord class OK
Class<?> ndefRecordClass = Class.forName("android.nfc.NdefRecord");

//getting ArrayOf NdefRecord
Object[] ndefRecords = (Object[])Array.newInstance(ndefRecordClass, 1)

//filling the new Array
//I'm shure I get an Correct NdefRecord, but dont wanna mess the Code here
ndefRecords[0] = getNdefRecord()

//getting the constructor OK
Constructor<?> const = ndefMessageClass.getConstructor(ndefRecords.class)

//initialization fails here
Object myNdefMessage = const.newInstance(ndefRecords)

//same with this
Object ndefMessage = const.newInstance(Arrays.asList(args).toArray());
```

I can absolutly NOT think of how this can fail, getting following ErrorMessage:

> 04-16 15:38:42.113: W/System.err(13360): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument 1 should have type android.nfc.NdefRecord[], got android.nfc.NdefRecord

So I get a Constructor recognized correctly. If I try to get it like this:

```
 Constructor<?> const = ndefMessageClass.getConstructor(ndefRecords[0].getClass())
```

I get

> 04-16 15:44:59.621: W/System.err(14033): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class android.nfc.NdefRecord]

while on Debugging it shows me everythis correct. I can access indices of my Array. WHY the hell java tells me that ndefRecords are of class NdefRecords instead of NdefRecords[]??

Comment: Why are you doing any of this in the first place? Dump the reflection, as you do not need it. Set your build target to API Level 9 and just use the APIs directly, wrapped in a `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` guard block to prevent it from being executed on older versions of Android. If you are still supporting Android 1.x, isolate the NFC code in a separate class that only ever gets loaded on API Level 9 or higher.

Comment: due to some BuisnessDecisions I'm not allowed to Set my build target up.

Comment: Whoever created these "BuisnessDecisions" needs to be fired. A given build target does not prevent your application from running on older versions of Android. Maintaining an artificially low build target simply increases the complexity of using newer Android features, as your question amply demonstrates.

Comment: Yes I agree, but arguing about that is senseless. I guess the decision was made because of unexperienced Devs here that *could* use SDK-methods of a higher level than ours :( But now I wanna Know what causes this error myself for educational purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem is that the `newInstance` [method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object...%29) is diamond function (i.e. function that takes variable number of parameters):

```
public T newInstance(Object... initargs)
```

In java, however you can pass in an array to such function and the elements of the array will be considered as consecutive parameters passed in to the function. Thus you get:

```
public static void main (String [] args)
{
   double [] a = {1.1, 2.2, 4.4};
   System.out.println(avg(a) == avg(1.1, 2.2, 4.4));
}
static double avg (double ... numbers)
{
   double total = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
        total += numbers [i];
   return total / numbers.length;
}
```

And the two calls to the `avg` function have exactly the same meaning.

One quick fix for you I can think of is to change your call to `newInstance` with:

```
Object myNdefMessage = const.newInstance(new Object[] {ndefRecords});
```

Comment: doesn't work: Error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument 1 should have type android.nfc.NdefRecord[], got java.lang.Object[][]`

Comment: @RafaelT Yes of course, sorry my bad. I fixed it now (hopefully).